# Autofill cell using text file and data from another cell

Tags: excel

Sorry for asking this but i did not found the answer. 

Case: 

Excel 2010, One sheet, Multiple unique text files with product data in one folder.

Cell A1 contain number "1000", cell B1 contain Directory path(C:/excel/). Cell C1 need to contain data from text file.

A1 - 1000 
B1 - C:/excel/
C1 - ALL TEXT DATA INSERTED FROM file C:/excel/1000.txt

I need C1 to be filled with the text data from file with path built using B1+A1+.txt
Also this need to be repeated in next rows. 
For collecting the needed data from cells i found my answer-

```
=CONCATENATE(B1;A1;".txt")
```

How can i populate the data from the text file in C1 ?
The text file contains this data:

```
<div>CANON CanoScan LiDE 210</div>
<div>• Type</div>
<div>Desktop Colour Flatbed Scanner</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Scanning element</div>
<div>CIS (Contact Image Sensor)</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Light source</div>
<div>3-colour (RGB) LED</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Optical resolution</div>
<div>4800 x 4800dpi</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Selectable resolution</div>
<div>25 - 19 200dpi</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Interface</div>
<div>Hi-Speed USB</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Scanning gradation (colour)</div>
<div>48 bit input - 48 or 24 bit output</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Scanning gradation (greyscale)</div>
<div>16 bit input - 8 bit output</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Maximum document size</div>
<div>A4 / Letter [216 x 297 mm]</div>
<div>• EZ-Scan Buttons</div>
<div>5 buttons (PDF, FINISH PDF, AUTO SCAN, COPY, E-MAIL) </div>
<div></div>
<div>• Preview speed</div>
<div>Approx. 9 sec.</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Scanning speed (colour)</div>
<div>2.2 msec. per line (300 dpi), 33.2 msec.per line (4800 dpi)</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Scanning speed (greyscale)</div>
<div>2.2 msec.per line (300 dpi), 11.1 msec.per line (4800 dpi)</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Scanning speed (B&W)</div>
<div>2.2 msec. per line (300 dpi), 11.1 msec. per line (4800 dpi)</div>
<div>• Scan speed (A4, 300dpi, Colour)</div>
<div>Approx. 10 sec.</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Power supply</div>
<div>Supplied via USB port</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Power consumption</div>
<div>approx. 2.5 W USB Powered (Operating) </div>
<div>approx. 1.4 W (Standby) </div>
<div>approx. 11 mW (Suspend) </div>
<div></div>
<div>• Dimensions</div>
<div>250 x 365 x 39 mm</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Weight</div>
<div>Approx. 1.6kg</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Operating range (temperature)</div>
<div>5 C to 35 C</div>
<div></div>
<div>• Operating range (humidity)</div>
<div>10% to 90% RH without condensation formation</div>
```

Sorry for my bad english, it didn't helped in google search too...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into the `indirect` function for excel, that should do it for the complete file path, and then a simple macro that opens that file, selects all cells, concatenates them into one cell, and then pastes that result into the cell `C1`.

Comment: I updated my question: How can i populate the C1 with the data from  this text file, the path of wich is built using B1+A1+txt

Comment: Is the data from your `C:/excel/1000.txt` file in a single cell (maybe `A1` as in my example below) and on a single sheet (called `Sheet1` in my example below)? If so you can do this with an `indirect` function, `=indirect("'["&CONCATENATE(B1,A1,".txt")&"]Sheet1!'A1`

Comment: The file that need to be read is not xls... It is text file with data in it. And i need all data from the text file in one cell